# legitimate proof of complex arguments?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\operatorname{Re}(z_1)>0, \operatorname{Re}(z_2)>0$, then $\operatorname{Arg}(z_1z_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_1) + \operatorname{Arg}(z_2)$

My question is if the proof i used is legitimate.

So i converted these argumets into their complex equivalents:

$\operatorname{Arg}(z_1z_2) = e^{it_1} e^{it_2}$  (where $t$ is my angle measure)

So then $e^{(it_1 + it_2)} = \operatorname{Arg}(it_1+it_2) = \operatorname{Arg}(it_1) + \operatorname{Arg}(it_2)$

So my question mainly is if i am allowed to carry through the $\operatorname{Arg}$ operator as i did through the expression? If not then i guess it means i have to go the long route and do alot of $\cos$ and $\sin$ expansions....

Thanks

Comment: $re^{i\theta} \ne \arg z$, the $\theta$ is $\arg z$.

Comment: It's still false. Try $z = 1$.

Comment: Im not sure i fully follow, but when i tried what yu suggested theta was 0. I think i am missing something in my understanding

Comment: You wrote:$\operatorname{Arg}(z_1z_2) = e^{it_1}e^{it_2}$. Putting $z_1 = z_2 = 1$ Gives $\operatorname{Arg}(1) = e^{i0}e^{i0} = 1$, but $\operatorname{Arg}(1) = 0$

Comment: Oh. Ok i see what you mean....ugh, that means i'm going to have to write out all those trig  expressions and simplify doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[The equation
$${\rm Arg}(z_1z_2) = e^{it_1} e^{it_2}$$
doesn't make sense, as on the left hand side you have a real number in the interval $\ ]{-\pi},\pi[\ $, and on the right hand side a complex number of absolute value $1$.]

Let $z_k=r_ke^{i\phi_k}$ $\>(k=1,2)$ have positive real part. Then we may choose $\phi_k={\rm Arg}(z_k)$, and $|\phi_k|<{\pi\over2}$. (Note that all complex numbers with positive real part have an ${\rm Arg}$ of absolute value $<{\pi\over2}$.)  It follows that
$$z_1\>z_2=r_1\>r_2\>e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}$$
with $$|\phi_1+\phi_2|\leq|\phi_1|+|\phi_2|<\pi\ .$$
Ths shows that
$${\rm Arg}(z_1z_2)=\phi_1+\phi_2={\rm Arg}(z_1)+{\rm Arg}(z_2)\ .$$

Comment: I have a qustion, why do we restrict phi(k) to (-pi/2, pi/2)?   The rest of it makes sense except that

Comment: @dc3rd: See my edit.